# Yii2 DataFilter builds wrong condition

Tags: php, yii2, logic

I have to make filtering by date in reqest. I know about existing `yii\data\DataFilter` class, so I used it to solve the issue.

Actual request URL(example): `https://api.site.com/module/post?filter[from_date][>=]=100`
Don't worry about value **100**, we use UNIX in our policy.

I use `yii\rest\ActiveController` to perform actions, so I defined `dataFilter` property in `[[actions()]]`:

```php
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions();
    $actions['index']['dataFilter'] = [
        'class' => DataFilter::class,
        'attributeMap' => [
            'from_date' => 'date_success',
            'to_date' => 'date_success',
        ],
        'searchModel' => function () {
            return (new DynamicModel(['from_date', 'to_date']))
                ->addRule(['from_date', 'to_date'], 'integer', ['min' => 0]);
        },
    ];
    return $actions;
}
```

After the query is completed, an empty array is returned `[]`. I traced SQL queries:
[image]

As you can see there is "EQUALS" operand instead ">", which defined in query-string `?filter[from_date][>]=100`.

By default in `yii\rest\IndexAction` variable `$query` calls method `where($filter)`:

```php
/*
After successful filter build $filter variable becomes:
    $filter = [
        'date_success' => [
            '>' => 100,
        ],
    ]
*/

$query = $modelClass::find();
if (!empty($filter)) {
    $query->andWhere($filter);
}
```

Why it's happens? I debugged the code, and I find one interesting feature! In `yii\db\conditions\HashConditionBuilder`:

```php
public function build(ExpressionInterface $expression, array &$params = [])
{
    $hash = $expression->getHash();
    $parts = [];
    foreach ($hash as $column => $value) {
        if (ArrayHelper::isTraversable($value) || $value instanceof Query) {
            // IN condition
            // Executing will be here.
            // Yii2 thinks thats 'IN' condition, and builds as 'IN'.
            $parts[] = $this->queryBuilder->buildCondition(new InCondition($column, 'IN', $value), $params);
        } else {
            if (strpos($column, '(') === false) {
                $column = $this->queryBuilder->db->quoteColumnName($column);
            }
            if ($value === null) {
                $parts[] = "$column IS NULL";
            } elseif ($value instanceof ExpressionInterface) {
                $parts[] = "$column=" . $this->queryBuilder->buildExpression($value, $params);
            } else {
                $phName = $this->queryBuilder->bindParam($value, $params);
                $parts[] = "$column=$phName";
            }
        }
    }
    return count($parts) === 1 ? $parts[0] : '(' . implode(') AND (', $parts) . ')';
}
```

This problem repeats with different 'conditionOperators', the result absolutely same.

```
filter[from_date][=]=100
filter[from_date][<]=100
filter[from_date][gt]=100
filter[from_date][gte]=100
```

Comment: Could you check if it works with `ActiveDataFilter` instead of `DataFilter`? It uses format suitable for `QueryInterface`.

Comment: @Bizley, Oh man thank you! It really works. I want to vote for your answer :)

Comment: May be I need to explore why this is happens and self-answer.

Comment: Undestanding what and why it works like that is always better than simply taking the answer so by all means please do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were one sticky difference between `ActiveDataFilter` and `DataFilter`. It concluse in method `[[buildInternal()]]`.

`DataFilter` method:

```php
protected function buildInternal()
{
    return $this->normalize(false);
}
```

`ActiveDataFilter` method:

```php
protected function buildInternal()
{
    $filter = $this->normalize(false);
    if (empty($filter)) {
        return [];
    }
    return $this->buildCondition($filter);
}
```

By calling `$this->buildCondition($filter)` `ActiveDataFilter` passes `$filter` variable and then applyes QueryBilders, so `$filter` variable becomes:

```php
$filter = ['>', 'date_success', 100];
```